# How to divide each column with a number and adding the last columns value in one step

Tags: python, numpy, frequency, cumsum

I am collecting a lot of data with a microcontroller including the controllers frequency. I want to use that frequency to calculate the time-steps between measurements. How do I code that in python?

I have tried using cumsum and other functions, but they do not work in my case. Therefore, I am thinking of using a for-loop, but I cant figure out the logic of the code. Here is how I import my data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datetime as dt
from IPython.display import display

csvfile = 'datafile.csv'
disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sql_data_server.db')

start = dt.datetime.now()
chunksize = 20000
j = 0
index_start = 1

for df in pd.read_csv(csvfile, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, encoding='utf-8-sig'):

    df.index += index_start
    j += 1
    print('{} seconds: completed {} rows'.format((dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds, j * chunksize))

    df.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
    index_start = df.index[-1] + 1

# SELECTED DATA
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Frequency FROM data ', disk_engine)    
Frequency = df.Frequency
```

Output:

```
Sample    Ax   Ay    Az    Gx    ...        q1    q2   q3   Temp  Frequency
0       0 -0.04 -0.0 -1.01 -0.03    ...     -0.16  0.99  0.0  23.74     330.80
1       1 -0.03 -0.0 -1.01  0.08    ...     -0.16  0.99  0.0  23.73     328.52

[2 rows x 13 columns]
0 seconds: completed 20000 rows
1 seconds: completed 40000 rows
2 seconds: completed 60000 rows
2 seconds: completed 80000 rows
3 seconds: completed 100000 rows
4 seconds: completed 120000 rows
5 seconds: completed 140000 rows
6 seconds: completed 160000 rows
6 seconds: completed 180000 rows
7 seconds: completed 200000 rows
8 seconds: completed 220000 rows
9 seconds: completed 240000 rows
9 seconds: completed 260000 rows
10 seconds: completed 280000 rows
11 seconds: completed 300000 rows
12 seconds: completed 320000 rows
13 seconds: completed 340000 rows
14 seconds: completed 360000 rows
14 seconds: completed 380000 rows
15 seconds: completed 400000 rows
16 seconds: completed 420000 rows
17 seconds: completed 440000 rows
17 seconds: completed 460000 rows
```

I have the frequency measurements (df.Frequency) in a column as int64 and I want to use that data to calculate time-steps in between meausurements. I think it is easier to understand if I just show you my thought proces. I have carried out the calculations in Excel in the following manner:

Timestep

Row 1: 1/330,8

Row 2: Row 1 + (1/328,52)

Row 3: Row 2 + (1/329,49)

... And so on.

Hope you can help.

Comment: When I read the title I thought to myself: great, I can answer that. But then I saw the question and was disappointed that it cannot be answered because there's no sample data or output.

Comment: I am new in here, sorry. What do you need to answer the question?

Comment: A [MCVE], please.

Comment: I have edited the post. Do you have sufficient information?